# Range filter on a dimension in SAP Analytics Cloud

Tags: sap-analytics-cloud

I need to create a range filter in SAC and to create range filter in SAC, column should either be date or number type.

I wanted to create a range filter on a Dimension but in SAC dimension is automatically converted into Text.

I am using excel to upload my data, I formatted the data in excel and made that dimension as number in it but once I upload the file in SAC that dimension automatically gets converted to Text.

I there any solution to this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create Measure based dimensions and give it a try. Since SAC will accepts measure as numeric. I hope this may help you.